# How to put another Layout on top of Scrollview

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I am using this (https://github.com/blessenm/AndroidAutoScrollListView) example to create a auto scroll view. Its working fine. To make it bit complex, I wanted another Layout on top of Scrollview. So i wrote the following layout. But then it is not showing scrollview.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >
   <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="1.0"
       android:fadingEdge="none" android:id="@+id/vertical_scrollview_id" android:background="#ffffff"
       android:scrollbars="none">
       <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/vertical_outer_layout_id" android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal">
       </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/logo"/>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/horizontalLine"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_margin="60dp"
            android:background="#c0c0c0"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/button_signup_margin_horizantal"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/button_signup_margin_horizantal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/button_signup_margin_verticle"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_signup"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:text="Sign Up"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_login"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/button_signup_margin_horizantal"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/button_signup_margin_horizantal"

                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn_signup"
                android:text="Log in"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Swipe to Learn more >>"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Is it possible to put a layout on top scrollview ? Thanks for your time.

**EDIT**
[image]

Comment: Do you mean, add another LinearLayout child inside of the ScrollView? If so, no. You can add 2 layouts inside of the linearlayout that's inside of scrollview tho.

Comment: No Vancert. Could you please check the screenshot i updated now. Thats what my requirement is. A scrollview in the backgroung and Login Layout in the foregroud.

Comment: Do you really have to use FrameLayout as your root view? If not, try using a relative layout instead and placing your child views in the desired position.

Comment: nothing in you scrollview linear layout add somthin in that and try..

Comment: You can use RelativeLayout as parent element and inside RelativeLayout use ScrollView and other RelaytiveLayout as child elements, give child RelativeLayout background as transparent and  height to match parent. And don't give layout position to both scrollview and RelativeLayout , in this way RelativeLayout will overlay on scrollview

Answer (score 1):

After some googling and Shreenivas' hint, Here is the answer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/vertical_scrollview_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/vertical_outer_layout_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I had included my overlay layout inside the ScrollView and it wasn't showing.  Once I moved it outside the ScrollView, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope it helps you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/vertical_scrollview_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/vertical_outer_layout_id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/logo3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/horizontalLine"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_margin="60dp"
            android:background="#c0c0c0" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:text="Sign Up"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_login"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn_signup"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Log in"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:text="Swipe to Learn more >>"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```